# Create a ContourPlot3d graph of a function (x,y,z) that contains series

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

As I said, I want to create a three-dimensional contour plot of a function that contains series of x and y. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
    ContourPlot3D[z - 400/(Pi)^2 \!\(
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(10\)]\((
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(10\)]\((\((
    \*FractionBox[\(1 - 
    \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(m\)]\), \(m\)])\) \((
    \*FractionBox[\(1 - 
    \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)]\), \(n\)])\) Exp[\(-\((
    \*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)] + 
    \*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)])\)\) t] Sin[m\ x] Sin[n\ y])\))\)\),
    {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: The variable "t" has no value.

Comment: Thank you, hehehe! I've already fixed that problem and I'm able to obtain the graphic, but the only  problem is that it takes quite time to be displayed. Is there a way to speed up that?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[z - 400/(Pi)^2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(10\)]\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(10\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(m\)]\), \(m\)])\) \((
\*FractionBox[\(1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)]\), \(n\)])\) Exp[\(-\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)])\)\)] Sin[m\ x] Sin[n\ y])\))\)\) // 
  Evaluate,
     {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z, 0, 100}]`

Comment: For what values of t you want the plot? Depending on the value of t you can speed up (or slow down) the creation of the figure.

Comment: Convert code to `InputForm` prior to copy and paste into MSE.